# What is the API level of Android R/11 to set in build.gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-11

I can use API R via Android Studio Emulator. I know I can run directly from Android Studio but still I want to set in Gradle level.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Now that the Android 11 (also known as Android R) SDK is released, the compile SDK version is simply `30`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 30 // Optional: If you want to target R as well
        // ...
    }
    // ... 
}
```

---

**No longer applicable:**

<s>When Android R was in the preview stage, the compile SDK version was `'android-R'` and the target SDK version was `'R'`:</s>

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-R'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 'R' // Optional: If you want to target R as well
        // ...
    }
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: What is the reason, the 'R' have been changed to 30? Is it common for new Android releases first use a letter and next the API number?